# Build fails with Kotlin kapt and Room

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, android-room, kotlin-android-extensions

When I try to use Architecture Components with Kotlin I get an strange compiler error.

The Gradle-Output:

```
Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Configuration 'compile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use 'implementation' instead.
Configuration 'androidTestCompile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use 'androidTestImplementation' instead.
Configuration 'testCompile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use 'testImplementation' instead.
'kapt.generateStubs' is not used by the 'kotlin-kapt' plugin
'kapt.generateStubs' is not used by the 'kotlin-kapt' plugin
'kapt.generateStubs' is not used by the 'kotlin-kapt' plugin
'kapt.generateStubs' is not used by the 'kotlin-kapt' plugin
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:splitsDiscoveryTaskDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources
:app:generateDebugSources
:app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:splitsDiscoveryTaskDebugAndroidTest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mockableAndroidJar UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
21 actionable tasks: 5 executed, 16 up-to-date
Executing tasks: [clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Configuration 'compile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use 'implementation' instead.
Configuration 'androidTestCompile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use 'androidTestImplementation' instead.
Configuration 'testCompile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use 'testImplementation' instead.
'kapt.generateStubs' is not used by the 'kotlin-kapt' plugin
'kapt.generateStubs' is not used by the 'kotlin-kapt' plugin
'kapt.generateStubs' is not used by the 'kotlin-kapt' plugin
'kapt.generateStubs' is not used by the 'kotlin-kapt' plugin
:clean
:app:clean
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild
:app:compileDebugAidl
:app:compileDebugRenderscript
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig
:app:generateDebugResValues
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources
:app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:splitsDiscoveryTaskDebug
:app:processDebugResources
:app:generateDebugSources
:app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl
:app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:splitsDiscoveryTaskDebugAndroidTest
:app:processDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources
:app:mockableAndroidJar

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2s
23 actionable tasks: 23 executed
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Configuration 'compile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use 'implementation' instead.
Configuration 'androidTestCompile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use 'androidTestImplementation' instead.
Configuration 'testCompile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use 'testImplementation' instead.
'kapt.generateStubs' is not used by the 'kotlin-kapt' plugin
'kapt.generateStubs' is not used by the 'kotlin-kapt' plugin
:app:buildInfoDebugLoader
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:splitsDiscoveryTaskDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources
:app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin
Using kotlin incremental compilation
:app:kaptDebugKotlin
w: warning: Supported source version 'RELEASE_7' from annotation processor 'android.arch.persistence.room.RoomProcessor' less than -source '1.8'
w: 

w: /Users/maxgierlachowski/Projects/jooy/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/jooyapp/jooy/Persistence/Entities/Message.java:17: warning: Primary key constraint on chatId is ignored when being merged into com.jooyapp.jooy.Persistence.Entities.Message
w: 

w:     private com.jooyapp.jooy.Persistence.Entities.Chat chat;
w:                                                        ^
w: /Users/maxgierlachowski/Projects/jooy/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/jooyapp/jooy/Persistence/Entities/Message.java:20: warning: Primary key constraint on userId is ignored when being merged into com.jooyapp.jooy.Persistence.Entities.Message
w: 

w:     private com.jooyapp.jooy.Persistence.Entities.User user;
w:                                                        ^

e: /Users/maxgierlachowski/Projects/jooy/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/jooyapp/jooy/Persistence/DatabaseAccessObjects/ChatDataAccessObject.java:19: error: no viable alternative at input 'chat_id'
e: 

e:     public abstract com.jooyapp.jooy.Persistence.Entities.Chat getChat(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
e:                                                                ^
e: /Users/maxgierlachowski/Projects/jooy/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/jooyapp/jooy/Persistence/DatabaseAccessObjects/UserDataAccessObject.java:9: error: no viable alternative at input 'user_id'
e: 

e:     public abstract com.jooyapp.jooy.Persistence.Entities.User getUser(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
e:                                                                ^

w: warning: Supported source version 'RELEASE_7' from annotation processor 'android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleProcessor' less than -source '1.8'
w: 


e: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to analyze: org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.diagnostic.KaptError: Error while annotation processing
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.analyzer.AnalysisResult.throwIfError(AnalysisResult.kt:57)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:144)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:167)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:55)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.exec(CLICompiler.java:182)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.execCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:397)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.access$execCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:99)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$1$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:365)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$1$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:99)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$2$$special$$inlined$withValidClientOrSessionProxy$lambda$1.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:798)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$2$$special$$inlined$withValidClientOrSessionProxy$lambda$1.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:99)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.DummyProfiler.withMeasure(PerfUtils.kt:137)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.checkedCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:825)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.access$checkedCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:99)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:797)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:99)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.ifAlive(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1004)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.ifAlive$default(CompileServiceImpl.kt:865)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.doCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:791)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.access$doCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:99)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$1.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:364)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$1.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:99)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.ifAlive(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1004)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.ifAlive$default(CompileServiceImpl.kt:865)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:336)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:346)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.diagnostic.KaptError: Error while annotation processing
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing(annotationProcessing.kt:90)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing$default(annotationProcessing.kt:42)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.runAnnotationProcessing(Kapt3Extension.kt:205)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:166)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.ClasspathBasedKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:82)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM$analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$2.invoke(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:89)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:99)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$default(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:76)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:365)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.analyzeAndReport(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.kt:105)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:354)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:139)
    ... 40 more


:app:kaptDebugKotlin FAILED
:app:buildInfoGeneratorDebug

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> Internal compiler error. See log for more details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED in 3s

15 actionable tasks: 6 executed, 9 up-to-date
```

The Gradle-File:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.jooyapp.jooy"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

    compile "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$lifecycle_version"
    kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$lifecycle_version"

    compile "android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:$lifecycle_version"
    compile "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$lifecycle_version"
    kapt "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:$lifecycle_version"

    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0-RC0'
    kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.0.0-RC0'

    compile "com.android.support:support-compat:$support_library_version"
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$support_library_version"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:$support_library_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$support_library_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$support_library_version"

    compile "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.11"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11"

}
```

The parameters:

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.3-2'
ext.lifecycle_version = '1.0.0-alpha5'
ext.support_library_version = '26.0.0'
```

I have already tried changing lifecycle_version but that didn't help either. When using annotationProcessor instead of kapt on this line:

```
kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$lifecycle_version"
```

I get another error because the Code from the annotations is not created but the other error seems to be gone.

The ChatDAO:

```
package com.jooyapp.jooy.Persistence.DatabaseAccessObjects

import android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData
import android.arch.persistence.room.Dao
import android.arch.persistence.room.Insert
import android.arch.persistence.room.Query
import com.jooyapp.jooy.Persistence.Entities.Chat
import com.jooyapp.jooy.Persistence.Entities.Message

@Dao
interface ChatDataAccessObject {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM Messages WHERE chat_id = :chatId")
    fun getMessagesForChat(chatId: String): LiveData<List<Message>>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM Messages WHERE chat_id = :chatId LIMIT :limit")
    fun getMessagesForChat(chatId: String, limit: Int): LiveData<List<Message>>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM Chats WEHRE chat_id = :chatId")
    fun getChat(chatId: String): Chat

    @Insert
    fun addChat(chat: Chat)

}
```

The UserDAO:

```
package com.jooyapp.jooy.Persistence.DatabaseAccessObjects

import android.arch.persistence.room.Dao
import android.arch.persistence.room.Insert
import android.arch.persistence.room.Query
import com.jooyapp.jooy.Persistence.Entities.Message
import com.jooyapp.jooy.Persistence.Entities.User

@Dao
interface UserDataAccessObject {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM Users WEHRE user_id = :userId")
    fun getUser(userId: String): User

    @Insert
    fun addUser(user: User)

}
```

The Database:

```
package com.jooyapp.jooy.Persistence

import android.arch.persistence.room.Database
import android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase
import com.jooyapp.jooy.Persistence.DatabaseAccessObjects.ChatDataAccessObject
import com.jooyapp.jooy.Persistence.DatabaseAccessObjects.MessageDataAccessObject
import com.jooyapp.jooy.Persistence.DatabaseAccessObjects.UserDataAccessObject
import com.jooyapp.jooy.Persistence.Entities.Chat
import com.jooyapp.jooy.Persistence.Entities.Message
import com.jooyapp.jooy.Persistence.Entities.User

@Database(entities = arrayOf(Message::class, User::class, Chat::class), version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun chatDao(): ChatDataAccessObject
    abstract fun userDao(): UserDataAccessObject
    abstract fun messageDao(): MessageDataAccessObject
}
```

And the Code of User:

```
package com.jooyapp.jooy.Persistence.Entities

import android.arch.persistence.room.Entity
import android.arch.persistence.room.ColumnInfo
import android.arch.persistence.room.PrimaryKey

@Entity(tableName = "Users")
data class User(
        @ColumnInfo(name = "user_id")
        @PrimaryKey
        var userId: String,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
        var name: String,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "phone")
        var phone: String,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "avatar_url")
        var avatarUrl: String?
)
```

Comment: Can you also give the code of `User` ?

Comment: @guillaume I have added the code of User, it's just a Simple Data-Class with the required fields

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo in your queries `getChat` and `getUser` you're using `WEHRE` instead of `WHERE`.